# How call object methods from a jquery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Maybe I am missing something, but I can't figure out how can I call one of the methods of the Listviewclass from the click callback.

Here's the code:

```
function Listview(el, cb) {

    this.element = el;
    this.callback = cb;

    this.select = function (element, index) {
        ...
    };

    this.selectElement = function (element) {
        ...
    };

    this.unselectCurrentElement = function () {
        ...
    };

    this.element.find('li').click(function () {
        // Here I want to call for example the selectElement method
        // but how? 
        // The This keyword reference the "li" element
    });

    this.element.addClass("Listview");
    this.select(this.element, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You have several options:

1. Since you're defining your `click` handler function inline anyway, use a local variable your handler closes over:

   ```
   var inst = this;
   this.element.find('li').click(function () {
       // `inst` is your instance, `this` is the element
       inst.selectElement(this);
   });
   ```
2. Use jQuery's [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy):

   ```
   this.element.find('li').click($.proxy(function (e) {
       // `this` is your instance, `e.currentTarget` is the element
       this.selectElement(e.currentTarget);
   }, this));
   ```
3. Use ES5's [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

   ```
   this.element.find('li').click(function (e) {
       // `this` is your instance, `e.currentTarget` is the element
       this.selectElement(e.currentTarget);
   }.bind(this));
   ```